# inserting many row of inputs from checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning to insert a data from my form using check box

that is

```
 <th><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" id="chkAll"  class="chkAll"/>With Pay</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="pay[]" id="chkAll2" class="chkAll2"/>Without Pay</th>
```

and i do have a many row of inputs here

how can i do this please help thanks

Comment: did you tried any code then please share?

Comment: insert in what table ? what did you try so far ?

Comment: actually i cant think of any code sorry please help

Answer (score 0):

Wrapp all input fields in a div and hide that div like

```
<div id="pay-inputs" style="display:none">
    <!-- input fields -->
</div>
```

and when you click on checkbox display the div using jquery like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chkAll").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $("#pay-inputs").show();
        } else {
            $("#pay-inputs").hide();
        }
    });
});
```